# Adding Ubuntu installation to VIsta boot loader

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Vista boot loader instead of GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/96590/using-vista-boot-loader-instead-of-grub)

Hi,

I had a Vista partition and created a partition and installed Ubuntu 9.10. During the Ubuntu installation I unchecked "Install Boot Loader" so it didn't install the GRUB bootloader.

I wanted to keep Vistas boot loader so I could manage it within Vista as I know you can - Ive just forgot where in the Control Panel you do it!

Anyway for some reason I incorrectly assumed that the Ubuntu entry would be added to the Vista boot loader.

How do enable to choose which OS to use during booting up the computer as at the moment it just automatically loads Vista?

Apologies if I'm technically incorrect - what I explained is what I thought was going on!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the vista cli tool [bcdedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28WS.10%29.aspx) or the alternative easybcd.

easybcd has a tutorial to dual boot ubuntu and vista [here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'd rather just comment but to add to Christian's answer, since you are using Ubuntu 9.10, I believe it uses neogrub instead of the old grub so if you do decide to use easybcd, you'll need to use the 2.0 version (Disclaimer: I believe this is in beta so use at your own risk. I myself have used this though and it worked fine.)

Get here: neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642

You can look at where it mentions Ubuntu 9.10 in #7 in this post for details about this: http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=3153

(can't even post 2 links so just add the http:// to that first one...)