# Using Vista boot loader instead of GRUB

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, multi-boot

I had Vista installed on a partition and I installed Ubuntu on the remaining free space.

Now when I boot the computer the OS selection screen is GRUB. Ive used EasyBCD to configure my Vista boot loader. How do I get the computer to use the Vista boot loader when it boots instead of GRUB?

I need to do something in Ubuntu but not sure what!!

Advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EasyBCD, select **Reinstall the Vista Bootloader** then **Write MBR**. Then in Linux, [follow the steps](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Linux) to add Linux to the Vista Bootloader. You need to install Linux onto a hidden bootsector as shown in that guide.

[image]

I'd suggest making a backup of the bootloader's settings first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial for you:

**[How to use Windows Vista’s Boot Manager to boot Linux](http://port25.technet.com/archive/2006/10/13/Using-Vista_2700_s-Boot-Manager-to-Boot-Linux-and-Dual-Booting-with-BitLocker-Protection-with-TPM-Support.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a set of instructions](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fright-now-in-tech.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F08%2Fuse-windows-bootloader-to-boot-windows.html&ei=uvd0TKUww6txxfTN3gU&usg=AFQjCNHSiAxkXaB0lJEhFt43atVDIL1SZw&sig2=qjhEpxg6EQYwYdamnc81MA) guiding you through exactly what you want on my blog:

When I boot the computer first, I have two options, nothing else:

Windows Vista
Ubuntu 10.04

Optionally, you can set it up like mine. If I don't do anything for 5 seconds, Windows fires up.