# How to boot into Linux (Ubuntu) with Windows Bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub, mbr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Vista boot loader instead of GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/96590/using-vista-boot-loader-instead-of-grub)

OK, so I had Windows Vista on a drive, and then installed Ubuntu Jaunty on another drive.  When I did that, grub took over.  I had many problems the first time and grub wouldn't load, it gave me an error 15.  I fixed it with [SuperGrub](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/), but it broke my RAID (which didn't have any OS).  I eventually got everything fixed up, and grub was working great.

Anyway, what happened now is I installed Windows 7 and got rid of Vista.  When I did that, I guess Windows wrote over the MBR with its own bootloader and so I'm not able to boot into linux anymore.  So, to be honest I couldn't care less about grub, and I don't want to run into the trouble of breaking my RAID again (actually I tried to install grub and this time got an error 17 so I used the Windows 7 CD to fix the MBR).

Now here is my question (sorry for that long intro haha), is it possible to get a grub-like interface when booting up so that I can choose whether to boot into Windows or Ubuntu?  If so, how?

Basically, you know when you get to choose whether to boot into safe-mode etc... I want that but with Ubuntu as an option.  Even if thats not possible, could you explain how to boot into Linux without installing grub?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/96590/using-vista-boot-loader-instead-of-grub

Comment: hmmm true, should i delete it?  the question has its differences though (multiple harddisks, windows 7, grub-like interface), but yeah the answer is the same.

Comment: no, don't delete it.  this one will be closed so no more answers can be added, but will be left for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: In future, please review all the duplicates listed during the Ask the Question stage before asking a question. Duplicate questions will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).  It makes editing the Windows Vista/7 bootload much easier by exposing it in a GUI.  It supports adding a Linux OS into the bootloader as well as older Windows versions.

Additionally you can used the command line tool [`bcdedit.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa906217.aspx), but EasyBCD is much easier IMHO.

Comment: In future please confirm a question is not a duplicate before answering. Duplicate questions should be closed. Providing answers to these questions encourages new users to do the same instead of flagging questions to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, EasyBCD should be able to handle it as already mentioned. For future reference, if you install inside Windows via [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/), this is the default behavior. The Ubuntu option will be added to the Windows bootloader:

[image]

Comment: In future please confirm a question is not a duplicate before answering. Duplicate questions should be closed. Providing answers to these questions encourages new users to do the same instead of flagging questions to be closed.