# How to change the grub boot loader

Tags: multi-boot, grub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Vista boot loader instead of GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/96590/using-vista-boot-loader-instead-of-grub)

I have windows 7 installed. Then I installed ubuntu 10.04 desktop.
The default boot loader was changed into grub boot loader. 
How do I change it back to default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from Windows7-DVD, open the recovery console and type:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

For more details to the commands visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Then reboot and start from your hard disk. This will recover bootmgr, but there won't be an entry for Ubuntu because bootmgr can only discover Windows automatically. You can use a tool like EasyBCD to change this manually. However I would use grub if there is no specific reason not to do so. You can also try the Windows-Ubuntu-Installer (Wubi). Just insert the Ubuntu-CD while running Windows7 and run wubi.exe. This will install Ubuntu inside your Windows7 partition and add an Ubuntu entry to bootmgr without overwriting it with grub. Then you can remove Ubuntu like any other software on Windows.