# Using Windows bootloader instead of GRUB2

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I installed Ubuntu onto a partition on my SSD along side an install of Windows 7. However, after booting the PC continued to boot into Windows without offering Ubuntu as an option. I found a solution mentioned here (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1499828&page=2) which uses GRUB2 for booting but I want to use the Windows bootloader. I found out about EasyBCD, wrote over the GRUB2 boot and followed the tutorials adding a Linux entry to the boot menu selecting the C:. I can then see both boot options in View Settings menu, but after restarting the computer it boots straight back into Windows and the options can no longer be seen in EasyBCD. I have no idea why this is going wrong, any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Vista boot loader instead of GRUB](http://superuser.com/questions/96590/using-vista-boot-loader-instead-of-grub)

Comment: Yeah, very similar, with the key difference that I have tried the provided solution and followed numerous tutorials on it but it hasn't solved the issue. The settings that are changed by EasyBSD seem to vanish and revert back to Windows 7 being the only bootable option.

Answer (score 0):

Despite being partitioned, the SSD in question is still physically one drive, and is therefore recognized as such in the BIOS and by the SATA controller within your computer. This being said, Windows Bootloader also only recognizes the SSD by the fact that it is a single drive and not in fact a drive separated into 2 partitions, each partition with its own bootable OS; Windows Bootloader only knows the drive by the fact that it can be booted to. This is why the Windows Bootloader doesn't show at boot/only shows one option to boot to.

GRUB2, on the other hand, can recognize the SSD as being split into 2 partitions, each with operating systems, and therefore handles them as such. It is not possible, with Windows Bootloader, to boot into separate Operating Systems on a partitioned drive, as Windows Bootloader is incapable of recognizing partitions on a drive.

Comment: I have tried this on my HDD and EasyBCD still behaves exactly the same.

Comment: doesn't matter weather or not its an HDD or an SDD, you'd still get the same results.